# Why are some elements diatomic under normal conditions while others are not?

Tags: molecules, elements

I see that the the standard form of many elements are diatomic molecules under normal conditions (eg oxygen, hydrogen and iodine are usually seen as diatomic molecules) and are all among the most electronegative, and I understand it has to do with energy and stability, but I just have no clue why other elements wouldn't be the same.

What explains why some appear as diatomic molecules and others do not?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/which-elements-can-be-diatomic

Comment: It's not really correct to say "diatomic elements" - it's implying certain universality, which just isn't there. Like every element can make diatomic molecules. And the ones being exceptions still can make diatomic "Van der Waals molecules".

Comment: On the other hand the elements you think diatomic can be also monoatomic, or even metallic.

Comment: @Mithoron. Can iron, aluminium, copper and lead make diatomic molecules ?

Comment: @Maurice Most likely. Exception I was thinking about is mercury https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108186/does-a-neutral-dimercury-molecule-exist and even this is arguable. Clear cut examples are likely only noble gases,

Comment: About lead, for example https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp810107c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which elements can be diatomic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/which-elements-can-be-diatomic)

Comment: Perhaps bigger issue is that this pretty much asks why **all elements** are as they are. Not only [oxygen vs sulfur](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/oxygen-and-sulfur-bonding) and [nitrogen vs phosphorus](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/why-does-nitrogen-form-n%e2%82%82-and-not-n%e2%82%84-while-but-phosphorus-forms-p%e2%82%84-and-not-p%e2%82%82), but all of them.